# MySQL and PHP connection failing

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have an issue with PHP script not connecting to MySQL database. Below code always generates error:

```
$dbconn = @mysql_connect('SFDC1', '<username>', '<password>');
if (!$dbconn)
{
die('Error connecting to DB!');
}
```

There is no issue if I connect to the database using MySQL workbench with same credentials. Issue only occurs during the communication between PHP and MySQL. 
Any help on debug of this issue?

Comment: 1st: `mysql_*`  is old, deprecated, removed in php7 (which version you are running?). 2nd: remove `@` to see the errors.

Comment: Try playing around between `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` for the mysql connection.

Comment: you should use mysqli or PDO instead of mysql_connect; http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php, http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Print the error message: `die(mysql_error())`

Answer (score -1):

Try this one;

```
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "username";
$dbpass = "pass";
$dbname = "DBname";

if(!@mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)) {
    echo "Cannot connect";
    die();
} else 
mysql_select_db($dbname);// or report();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this code to connect mysql.

```
<?php
    $dbconn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
    if (!$dbconn ) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Or don't, because the `mysql_*` functions don't even exist in modern PHP anymore.